# How can I align an existing drain trap with my new kitchen sink?

Tags: plumbing, drain

[image]Installed new kitchen sink and the drain is 4" off from the existing p-trap.

The below pics illustrate my problem. Today I will buying  a tailpiece with a dishwasher connect.

When the tailpiece is installed what other parts will be needed  to align the tailpiece with the existing p-trap setup?

Comment: Loosen the metal compression nut. Twist the trap counter-clockwise. Tighten the metal compression nut.

Comment: @brhans i'm not sure you read the question correctly.

Comment: That's how I read it, too, but it's difficult to tell from one angle whether swiveling the trap alone will do the trick. I'd be cutting off all the welded parts and installing a new reducer and threaded compression nipple, then using all compression fittings to complete the job.

Comment: @TheEvilGreebo - from that photo It looks to me as though the open end of the trap needs to swing over to the right. Loosening the slip-joint on the trap would allow that to happen. It's not clear from the angle of the shot whether or not that would be enough - but it's what needs to happen first...

Comment: I agree but what he asked was what parts does he need.

Comment: Make sure to loop the dishwasher hose as high up as possible. Ideally it should get to just under the counter - i.e., much higher than the bottom of the sink. Otherwise you are looking for trouble with smells and/or standing water in the dishwasher.

Comment: @TheEvilGreebo - we won't know what he needs until he swings it over. It's possible that the dishwasher tailpiece he's already planning to buy will be sufficient. It's possible that it won't. But without step one and a better view it's impossible to say. This is why I posted a *comment* and not an *answer*.

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty standard issue.  I'm a little confused why your drain end appears to have a permanent reducer coupling attached to it - but in any event they make a flexible, expanding part for just this issue:
[image]

Just install it and force the pipe into the best fitting position.  It connects to both ends with a compression ring.

Comment: You'd want to use this in conjunction with brhans' suggestion above.  The bend would be pretty severe otherwise.

Comment: Agreed.  You don't want any extreme bends or you'll be subject to clogging.